# NullReferenceException after deleting item from database, then redirecting to page showing the list of remaining items

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am getting a

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
> instance of an object.

when I delete an item from the SQLite database and I redirect to the Index page (which shows the list of items) via the function in the controller class.

The item does successfully delete from the database, and when I **manually** go to the Index page (by clicking in the navbar link) it works fine without errors and the list appears updated, but when I redirect **automatically** using the function in the controller, thats when the `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` occurs.

My problem is that I don't know how to fix this (I'm new to C# ASP.NET), but I can point out where the exception occurs in the example below on the **Index.cshtml** page.
I am using C#, ASP.NET 7, Razor Pages, SQLite

The relevant codes are here:

- **CategoriesController.cs**

**DeleteConfirmed** method which triggers the delete event and redirect to the Index page

```cs
// POST: Categories/Delete/5
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    await _logic.RemoveCategoryFromProducts(id);
    await _logic.RemoveCategory(id);
    return View("Index");
}
```

**Index** method to get the Index page

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var categories = await _logic.GetAllCategories();
    return View(categories);
}
```

**

- **Index.cshtml**- the null reference exception occurs on the `@foreach (var item in Model!)` because it gets a null reference when redirected via the function above, but when I open this page manually, the list is updated successfully.**

```
@using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
@model IEnumerable<CategoryModel>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model!) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Feel free to ask if you need any more code examples, it's my first question I've asked on StackOverflow so please don't mind :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Maybe you can check what the `GetAllCategories()` function is returning in your `Index()` function. If it's returning `null`, you know that that's the problem. Another option is that this `Index()` function is not called at all, meaning that there's no data available to loop through, causing the exception.

Comment: Sorry jmcilhinney but that doesn't address the issue.
DutchJelly, the function seems to work fine and doesn't return null.
@Jackdaw's solution has fixed the issue, but thank you guys for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `return View("Index");` line does not make redirect but renders the specified view. To make redirect use:

```cs
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

---

[RedirectToAction Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.redirecttoaction?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: Thanks Jack, that fixed my problem precisely and gave me clarification as to which function to use next time

Comment: @yt10: You are welcome!  Everything will also work fine if you will pass the data model as the second parameter:  `return View("Index", _logic.GetAllCategories());`

Answer (score 0):

The exception means that the Model is null.
The problem is under the method DeleteConfirmed in:

```
return View("Index");
```

This is not a redirection, you are only returning the View Index without passing the model. That is why you get a null reference on Model.
Instead if that use:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index")
```

This ensure to go throw the Controller method "Index" and behave like the opening of the page.

Comment: Thank you hatem for the solution, and your explanation helped me make sense of the issue, I appreciate it